# Two columns text with different languages

Tags: pdftex

Text with two columns, each column with text in different languages. For example, in the right column the text is in English and in the left column the same text in Portuguese.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide much information to go on. From what I understand, you want to pair an original text and it's translation paragraph by paragraph in two columns.

It seems you can use the package [paracol](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) to achieve this.
I made an example with the first chapter of a book and it's real translation.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    
\section*{Chapter 1}
\subsection{The Authors Demise}
For some time I debated over whether I should start these memoirs at the beginning or at the end, that is, whether I should put my birth or my death in first place. Since common usage would call for beginning with birth, two considerations led me to adopt a different method: the first is that I am not exactly a writer who is dead but a dead man who is a writer, for whom the grave was a second cradle; the second is that the writing would be more distinctive and novel in that way. Moses, who also wrote about his death, didn't place it at the opening but at the close: a radical difference between this book and the Pentateuch.
\switchcolumn
\section*{Capítulo 1}
\subsection{Óbito do Autor}
Algum tempo hesitei se devia abrir estas memórias pelo princípio ou pelo fim, isto é, se poria em primeiro lugar o meu nascimento ou a minha morte. Suposto o uso vulgar seja começar pelo nascimento, duas considerações me levaram a adotar diferente método: a primeira é que eu não sou propriamente um autor defunto, mas um defunto autor, para quem a campa foi outro berço; a segunda é que o escrito ficaria assim mais galante e mais novo. Moisés, que também contou a sua morte, não a pôs no intróito, mas no cabo; diferença radical entre este livro e o Pentateuco. 
\newline
\switchcolumn* 
With that said, I expired at two o'clock on a Friday afternoon in the month of August, 1869, at my beautiful suburban place in Catumbi. I was sixty-four intense and prosperous years old, I was a bachelor, I had wealth of around three hundred contols, and I was accompanied to the cemetery by eleven friends. Eleven friends! The fact is, there hadn't been any cards or announcements. On top of that it was raining--drizzling--a thin, sad, constant rain, so constant and so sad that it led one of those last-minute faithful friends to insert this ingenious idea into the speech he was making at the edge of my grave: "You who knew him, gentlemen, can say with me that nature appears to be weeping over the irreparable loss of one of the finest characters humanity has been honored with. This somber air, these drops from heaven, those dark clouds that cover the blue like funeral crepe, all of it is the cruel and terrible grief that gnaws at nature and at my deepest insides; all that is sublime praise for our illustrious deceased.

\switchcolumn
Dito isto, expirei às duas horas da tarde de uma sexta-feira do mês de agosto de 1869, na minha bela chácara de Catumbi. Tinha uns sessenta e quatro anos, rijos e prósperos, era solteiro, possuía cerca de trezentos contos e fui acompanhado ao cemitério por onze amigos. Onze amigos! Verdade é que não houve cartas nem anúncios. Acresce que chovia -peneirava- uma chuvinha miúda, triste e constante, tão constante e tão triste, que levou um daqueles fiéis da última hora a intercalar esta engenhosa idéia no discurso que proferiu à beira de minha cova: -«Vós, que o conhecestes, meus senhores, vós podeis dizer comigo que a natureza parece estar chorando a perda irreparável de um dos mais belos caracteres que tem honrado a humanidade. Este ar sombrio, estas gotas do céu, aquelas nuvens escuras que cobrem o azul como um crepe funéreo, tudo isso é a dor crua e má que lhe rói à natureza as mais íntimas entranhas; tudo isso é um sublime louvor ao nosso ilustre finado.
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.